# History and XHR issues with Sails running on localhost

Tags: json, ajax, cors, sails.js, mithril.js

With the default configuration, I am unable to make XHRs in my Mithril app if I run its Sails server in localhost. All I get is:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:1337/json/test-realms.json. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value ''. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

If I [enable CORS](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/sails.config/sails.config.cors.html) with `allRoutes: true, origin: '*'` that problem goes away, and instead I get:

> DOMException: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'http://localhost:1337/#!/' cannot be created in a document with origin 'null'.

What exactly is the issue here?

Updates:

- I am using `sails lift` as server.
- The web app is loaded via `http://test.pink`. The domain is set to a LAN IP via the HOSTS file.
- No resources are loaded via `file:///` or `localhost`.

Comment: The issues are most likely unrelated. The second problem is [common](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Failed+to+execute+%27replaceState%27+on+%27History%27) when attempting to make changes to history on local development sandboxes - what URL is your app running from, and what are you passing to Mithril's `m.route` to initialise it?

Comment: I tried to run it from the URLs `localhost:1337` (Sails default), `localhost` and `test.pink` with the HOSTS file pointing to a LAN IP. `m.route` is initialised with `!/` by default (an empty page in my app).

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was related to Content Security Policy. I had set `sandbox 'allow-scripts' 'allow-forms'`, which as per [this](http://content-security-policy.com/) and [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp) would treat the page as an iframe with an unique origin.

Disabling the `sandbox` policy or adding `allow-same-origin` suffices to fix it.